How can I add a simple web component?
is there a simple way of adding a web component into drupal ? I have tried it but my component doesnt show, it removes the non-html component tag entirely, it loads the js file properly and when i console log it, it returns a log only on static get observedAttributes() function.
js code:
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['message'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name === 'message') {
      this.render(newValue);
    }
  }

  render(message) {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        .message {
          font-size: 20px;
          color: blue;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="message">${message}</div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);

I'm adding a library with this web component through this hook:
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view() to add a library to the node view.
 *


Drupal's render API automatically sanitizes anything supposed to be parsed as HTML. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/10
This affects your '#markup' => '<my-component message="' . $message . '"></my-component>', part of the code, where the non-standard HTML tag is omitted from the output due to sanitization constraints, as your <my-component> tag is not in the whitelist of permitted tags.
From that page linked above:

#markup: Specifies that the array provides HTML markup directly. Unless the markup is very simple, such as an explanation in a paragraph tag, it is normally preferable to use #theme or #type instead, so that the theme can customize the markup. Note that the value is passed through \Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filterAdmin(), which strips known XSS vectors while allowing a permissive list of HTML tags that are not XSS vectors. (For example,  and  are not allowed.) See \Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::$adminTags for the list of allowed tags.


If your markup needs any of the tags not in this list, then you can implement a theme hook and/or an asset library. Alternatively, you can use the key #allowed_tags to alter which tags are filtered.

This video might help you: CREATING & CONSUMING WEB COMPONENTS FOR DRUPAL

I don't know what Drupal does.
Web Components are HTML just like any other HTML in CMSs;
shouldn't require any special handling in the CMS.
Check in the console for customElements.get("my-component")
should return the Component Class
If not the Javascript to define the component was not executed.
Your Web Component is missing a connectedCallback,
and the attributeChangedCallback fires before the element is connected in the DOM. (once for every Observed Attribute!)
So you have to guard that first attributeChangedCallback( "message" ,...) by checking for this.isConnected
The rest of the changes are just to optimize your Web Component


<script>
customElements.define('my-component', class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['message'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
      .innerHTML = `
          <style>
            div { font-size: 20px; color: blue }
          </style>
          <div></div>`;
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (this.isConnected) this[ name ]();
  }
  
  connectedCallback(){
    this.message();
  }

  message(msg = this.getAttribute("message") || "No message attribute!") {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div").innerHTML = msg;
  }
});
</script>

<my-component></my-component>
<my-component message="Hello Cool Web Component World!"></my-component>



Simplify your Web Component with a <slot>
For a (simple) message an attribute is not required.
A <slot> in shadowDOM will automagically display the lightDOM (innerHTML of the Web Component itself)
Also see named SLOTs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot
SLOTs are reactive;
document.querySelector("my-slot-component").innerHTML = "GREAT! Components!";
will update the reflected slot in shadowDOM
For long read & deep dive on styling slots see: ::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot


<script>
customElements.define('my-slot-component', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
      .innerHTML = `
          <style>
            div {
              font-size: 20px;
              color: blue;
            }
          </style>
          <div><slot>No message specified</slot></div>`;
  }
});
</script>

<my-slot-component></my-slot-component>
<my-slot-component>Hello Fantastic Web Component World!</my-slot-component>




Thanks I made the changes but it does not work in drupal still. It works perfectly fine when i put the script in html document and open it in a browser, but not in drupal.

Then the problem is loading the component (see my added console remark above); just whack in a 
Put a console.log("Loading my-component") at the top of your JS file, if that doesn't show the problem is on the Drupal side

As I immediately expected when OP wrote it removes the non-html component tag entirely, the problem is the standard XSS protection methods applied by Drupal when constructing HTML, see my answer.
